# Redirect after Login using Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using the built in loginButtons options with Meteor and I would like to redirect after a user logs in.  Using the built in web snippets means I can't use the callback with Meteor.loginwithPassword and I can't see any hooks inside Iron-Router to do the redirect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#using-hooks Router.before(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['login', 'signup', 'forgotPassword']});

Comment: I can't see any example pieces of code using this to see how to use it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Meteor often renders so quickly that the page is being loaded before the user has been defined.  You need to use `Meteor.loggingIn()` to account for the situation in which you are *in the process* of logging in. This code works for me:

```
this.route('myAccount', {
  path: '/',
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
      if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) Router.go('login');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) Router.go('login');`

Answer (score 6):

This example might be useful

```
// main route render a template
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('main');
});

// render login template
Router.route('/login', function () {
    this.render('login');
});  


// we want to be sure that the user is logging in
// for all routes but login
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if (!Meteor.user() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        // required by Iron to process the route handler
        this.next();
    }
}, {
    except: ['login']
});

// add here other routes

// catchall route
Router.route('/(.*)', function () {
    this.redirect('/catchallpage');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

it should be very easy just add something like:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var currentRoute = Router.current();
  if (currentRoute === null) {
    return;
  }

  if (currentRoute.route.getName() === 'login' && Meteor.user() !== null)
    Router.go('WelcomeNewUser');
  }
```

You can also just use the same route with another template in case the user is not logged in.

just something like this:

```
this.route('myAccount', {
   before: function () {
     if (!Meteor.user()) {
       this.render('login');
       this.stop();
     }
   }
}
```

There is no magic, just looked into the [docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#using-a-layout-with-yields) ;)

Comment: Note that `Deps` is now called `Tracker`.

Comment: Is there a way to undo `this.stop()` after the user logged in?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use one of your existing routes you have configured in Ireland route

Router.go('/myRouterPathToTemplate')

Comment: Can you add an example of how this would be implemented