# Show buttons if logged in, Meteor's Spacebars

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is my `layout.html`code, and Im wondering how to augment it so that `<div class="navbar"> ... </div>` only shows if the user is logged in via the `{{>loginButtons}}` above them.  Additionally, how do I route to the route triggered by one of the buttons, upon the user successfully logging in?

```
        <body>
            {{renderPage}}
        </body>

        <template name='layout'>

            <div class="layout-buttons">

                    {{> loginButtons}}
            </div>

            <div class="navbar">
                <div class='btn' id='left'><a class='button-text' href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">home</a></div>
                <div class='btn' id='right'><a class='button-text' href="{{pathFor 'speakers'}}">myKaleo</a></div>
            </div>

            {{> yield}}

        </template>
```

Comment: `{{#if currentUser}} your code {{/if}}`. We won't write code for you tho, can help with yours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [currentUser](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_loggingin) helper like so:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
  <div class="navbar">
    ...
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900405/how-to-redirect-after-user-has-just-logged-in-or-just-logged-out) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315896/redirect-after-login-using-meteor-and-iron-router) for how to automatically redirect the user.

Comment: what is the proper syntax for {{#if  !currentUser?}}  (not current user)

Comment: `{{#unless currentUser}} {{/unless}}`